# Split a sparse square matrix into blocks

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a banded sparse square matrix , A, of type `<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>` and size = 400 x 400. I'd like to split this into block square matrices of size 200 x 200 each. For instance, the first block

```
block1 = A[0:200, 0:200]
block2 = A[100:300, 100:300]
block3 = A[200:400, 200:400]
```

The same information about the slices is stored in a list of tuples.

```
 [(0,200), (100, 300), (200, 400)]
```

Suggestions on how to split the spare square matrix will be really helpful.

Comment: What have you tried?  Your `block1` etc indexing should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to a regular array and then split it:

```py
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import numpy as np

row = np.arange(400)[::2]
col = np.arange(400)[1::2]
data = np.random.randint(1, 10, (200))
compressed_matrix = csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(400, 400))

# Convert to a regular array
m = compressed_matrix.toarray()
# Split the matrix
sl = [(0,200), (100, 300), (200, 400)]
blocks = [m[i, i] for i in map(lambda x: slice(*x), sl)]
```

And if you want you can convert back each block to a compressed matrix:

```py
blocks_csr = list(map(csr_matrix, blocks))
```

**CODE EXPLANATION**

The creation of the blocks is based on a [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/#using-list-comprehensions) and basic slicing.
Each input tuple is converted to a [slice](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#slice) object, only to create a series of row and column indexes, corresponding to that of the elements to be selected; in this answer, this is sufficient to select the requested block squared matrix. Slice objects are generated when extended indexing syntax is used: To be clear, `a[start:stop:step]` will create a slice object equivalent to `slice(start, stop, step)`. In our case, they are used to dynamically change the indexes to be selected, according to the matrix we want to extract. So, if you consider the first block, `m[i, i]` is equivalent to `m[0:200, 0:200]`.

Slice objects are a form of [basic indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing), so a [view](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/glossary.html#term-view) of the original array is created, rather than a copy (this means that if you modify the view, also the original array will be modified: you can easily create a copy of the original data using the [`copy`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html) method of the numpy array).

The [`map`](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/#using-map-objects) object is used to generate slice objects from the input tuples; `map` applies the function provided as its first argument to all the elements of its second argument.
`lambda` is used to create an anonymous function, i.e., a function defined without a name. Anonymous functions are useful to accomplish specific tasks that you do not want to code in a standard function, because you are not going to reuse them or you need only for a short period of time, like in the example of this code. They make code more compact rather than defining the correspondent functions.

`*x` is called [unpacking](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unpacking-a-tuple-in-python), i.e you extract, unpack elements from the tuple. Suppose you have a function `f` and a tuple `a = (1, 2, 3)`, then `f(*a)` is equivalent to `f(1, 2, 3)` (as you can see, you can think of unpacking as removing a level of parentheses).

So, looking back at the code:

```py
blocks = [  # this is a list comprehension
    m[i, i]  # basic slicing of the input array
    for i in map(  # map apply a function to all the item of a list
        lambda x: slice(*x), sl  # creating a slice object out of the provided index ranges
    )
]
```

Comment: Could you please explain `blocks = [m[i, i] for i in map(lambda x: slice(*x), sl)]` a bit?

Comment: I've added a short explanation to the code :)

Comment: Late to the party, but I believe conversion to dense array should be done after getting the blocks if at all necessary in order to save memory and runtime.